# Android Facebook SDK samples : 'your project Contains error(s), please fix them before running your application'

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to learn Facebook integration to Android Apps. In the process, I followed the tutorial as explained [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/). I have a little knowledge on Android, but nothing on integrating Facebook to apps.

I have my Android Workspace in a different path (not the same as my Android SDK), in my Windows computer. I have added the Facebook SDK library to my workspace, and loaded a few sample examples from there - as explained in the above tutorial.

Everytime I try to build and run any of the Facebook samples, I get into the problem **'your project Contains error(s), please fix them before running your application'**.

When I goto my Problems View, I can see 1 error -> **'Error generating final archive : {Workspace-Location}\libs does not exist'**.

I went through a few related questions on this, and I have tried the following :

- Clean the project & rebuild
- Remove Automatic Building, and close eclipse, then restart, then clean, build & run
- go to .debug folder(under C:/USER/.android/), remove the debug.keystore, to generate new key
- ensure in android properties, the uncheck on 'is library' is obeyed.

All of the above has not helped me. I am stuck for more than a day, and internet search is not helping me.

I would be happy if someone can help me here.

Comment: Where is your facebook library?  Eclipse tends to expect all libraries to be in the libs folder under your project.  Try creating the directory by hand and putting any jars you use in there.

Comment: @GabeSechan - After downloading the facebook-android-sdk-3.7, I have placed it in my 'C:/' drive. My Eclipse Workspace is in 'F:/' drive. So, I have imported the FacebookSDK, by using the option 'Copy Projects into workspace' (this has made a copy of it in my workspace).  Can you explain how I can create the directory by hand and put the jars? I could not follow that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete the libs folder solve this problem for me

you could add libs folder back as below:

[image: add libs folder back by Android Tools]

Comment: Thanks a million. I somehow missed the warning symbol on the libs folder. Your answer has helped me a lot.